# Creating a div that disappears/shrinks as you scroll down?

Tags: html, css

I am interested in creating something similar to the header div here: http://abduzeedo.com/brainstorm-9-logo-process

I know that the html would look kinda like this:

```
<div class="menu">
    <!--Fixed menu-->
</div>

<div class="headerimg">
    <!--Image that would disapear-->
</div>

<div class="content">
    <!--Content stuff here-->
</div>
```

But I'm not sure how to do this on the jQuery/ CSS side. Any ideas?

Thanks, Harrison

Comment: Bind page scroll to image `transform: translateY()` property with jQuery/JS.

Comment: Did you look at there source and/or examine it with something like Firebug?

Comment: @Jim, I have done that in the past, but I am looking for a more detailed, straight forward answer than the code will give me, Thanks though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heres a fiddle doing it (nothing fancy, mainly playing with position: fixed; and z-index.): http://jsfiddle.net/zrYTm/7/

HTML:

```
<div class="menu"> Lorem ipsum dolor...</div>

<div class="headerimg"> Sed aliquam, lectus...</div>

<div class="content"> Fusce at neque...</div>
```

CSS:

```
.menu {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1000000; /* highest z-index on page */

    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
}

.headerimg {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 0; /* Lowest z-index */

    top: 100px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: green;
}

.content {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1000; /* Medium z-index */

    margin-top: 200px; /* Heigth of header and menu */

    height: 1000px;
    background-color: blue;
}

div {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It works good, in between you and aurel, they both work. So for the answer I choose you, since you where first to it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Using your html, here is the css:

```
 .menu, .headerimg, .content {
    width: 100%;
}
.menu {
    background: red;
    height: 50px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}
.headerimg {
    background: yellow;
    height: 100px;
    position: fixed;
    top:50px;
    z-index: -2;
}
.content {
    height: 1000px;
    background: gray;
    z-index:50;
    margin-top: 160px;
}
```

Now to get the `.headerimg` to scroll slower then the `.content`, use this bit of Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
window.onscroll = function () {
    n = Math.ceil($("body").scrollTop() / 4);
    $(".headerimg").css("-webkit-transform", "translateY(-" + n + "px)");
    $(".headerimg").delay(1300).css("-moz-transform", "translateY(-" + n + "px)");

}
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/akurtula/3w9Dv/1

Comment: Thanks! It works good, in between you and Jost, they both work. So for the answer I choose him, since he was first to it. Thank you very much though!